# How to split JavaFX Nodes on Class files if Stage needs to be invoked from Main class?

Tags: java, javafx

I really like that I can call classes/objects from main method. This way I don't have whole code in main method (that wouldn't really feel like object oriented programming).

Now I have a simple code that draws a line using JavaFX. The line is a node, which is inside scene. But it's all in the main method.

My main class is called **Example**. It contains whole code

I tried:

```
public static LineClass extends Example
```

Then I did put appropriate code there. Compiler didn't let me compile it because launch() needs to be invoked from main method. I then did what compiler asked me to do, but it would just find more errors.

My code (when it was working):

```
import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.scene.Group; 
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.shape.Line; 
import javafx.stage.Stage;  

public class DrawingLine extends Application{ 
   @Override 
   public void start(Stage stage) { 
      //Creating a line object 
      Line line = new Line(); 

      //Setting the properties to a line 
      line.setStartX(100.0); 
      line.setStartY(150.0); 
      line.setEndX(500.0); 
      line.setEndY(150.0); 

      //Creating a Group 
      Group root = new Group(line); 

      //Creating a Scene 
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300); 

      //Setting title to the scene 
      stage.setTitle("Sample application"); 

      //Adding the scene to the stage 
      stage.setScene(scene); 

      //Displaying the contents of a scene 
      stage.show(); 
   }      
   public static void main(String args[]){ 
      launch(args); 
   } 
}
```

How to split code for more classes (assuming each class has its own .class file)? My aim is to have the JavaFX code (graphics) for Line object/node in different .class file instead of having all that code in main method to avoid mess. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another class with the functionality you need, and instantiate it from `start()`.

```
import javafx.scene.Group ;
import javafx.scene.Parent ;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line ;

public class LineClass {

    private final Group root ;

    public LineClass() {

        //Creating a line object 
        Line line = new Line(); 

        //Setting the properties to a line 
        line.setStartX(100.0); 
        line.setStartY(150.0); 
        line.setEndX(500.0); 
        line.setEndY(150.0); 

        root = new Group(line); 
    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return root ;
    }
}
```

and then

```
import javafx.application.Application ;
import javafx.scene.stage.Stage ;
import javafx.scene.Scene ; 

public class DrawingLine extends Application{ 
   @Override 
   public void start(Stage stage) { 

      LineClass lc = new LineClass();

      //Creating a Scene 
      Scene scene = new Scene(lc.getView(), 600, 300); 

      //Setting title to the scene 
      stage.setTitle("Sample application"); 

      //Adding the scene to the stage 
      stage.setScene(scene); 

      //Displaying the contents of a scene 
      stage.show(); 
   }      
   public static void main(String args[]){ 
      launch(args); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @James_D but this code doesn't compile. I tested both Eclipse and NetBeans.

Comment: What compile error are you getting? It works fine for me.

Comment: Yes. I also included "package drawingline;" (which I missed I admit) yet it still returns errors http://i.imgur.com/SIBr70O.png. Maybe my IDE is not configured properly? However that code I included in question did compile successfully.

Comment: @PeterAnson Well, those errors are different. So I'm guessing you didn't actually add the imports in previously. You still seem to be missing the import for `Parent`.

Comment: @PeterAnson Seriously, did you even bother to read the error message? Where is your import for `Parent`?

Comment: @PeterAnson Added the imports, not sure why it is so difficult to figure that out.

Comment: Oh code works now. Unfortunately cant give you +1 because of limitations. Im sorry im programming for 4 days and importing parent wasnt in my code before so i didnt think about adding it. Ive clicked on something in IDE and it added automatically.  Thanks once again James! :)

Comment: @PeterAnson You can mark the answer as correct, no matter your reputation. Just as some advice, I don't think it's a very good idea to try to use a moderately advanced framework like JavaFX until you have a reasonable understanding of the basics of Java. You will end up trying to learn too many different things at once, and when things work you won't have a way to know where to start with troubleshooting. Do some Java intro tutorials before you try to use advanced libraries.

Comment: I've read many books (and even started reading Oracle tutorials) regarding basics (variables, classes, objects, loops, methods and so on) and I usually left the guide when I reached swing. Because JavaFX is successor to swing and people say Swing is outdated. I wanna code games and I guess using JavaFX is better for the future.